# Query check all parents are present

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables :

Item_category:

| id | item_id | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 |

And category:

| id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

All items have a category, and in table item_category I should also have rows with parent category. I try to make a query that show me all items where a parent category is missing. In this exemple item_id : 5 - category : 1 is missing, the query in SQL should show this row.
Any ideas?

Thx a lot for your help. Kinda stuck

Comment: really did not get your question , can you add more rows and an output example and may be more elaboration on how you want to handle parent_id and is your categor.id is same as item_category.category_id ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```sql
SELECT items.* FROM items LEFT JOIN item_category ON item_id = items.id LEFT JOIN category ON category_id = category.id WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```